# Hold Button is disabled

Tags: acumatica

Since version 2021R2, when I run registration update processing, I get the following message randomly

[image]

while the button is active,
[image]

I tried to enter the following code, but it does not change

```
     Base.releaseFromHold.SetEnabled(true);
```

I noticed that when I click on cancel, it works again, but when I put this code at the end of the processing, nothing happens

```
     Base.Actions.Cancel();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this indicates that the conditions that enabled the button when the screen updated are no longer met, thus disabling the button after it is clicked but before it is processed.  An example is when you have a field that is required for your action to be enabled, so it is enabled, but you delete the value and immediately try clicking the button.  It could be a bigger bug that you have found, but more likely it is that you hit the failsafe on the button so that it does not fire now that the required conditions are no longer met.

In 2022 R1 (and most if not all of 2021 R2, I believe), most of these conditions in standard Acumatica are in the workflows, which are coded in C# as seen in the code repository, normally with filenames ending in **_workflow.cs**.

While you did not specify where this hold button exists, the screenshot appears that you are trying to do this on the SOOrderEntry graph.  It has a complex workflow based on the Order Type but standard code appears to result in making an SO type Sales Order transition to *Open* status unless other conditions are met.  You did not provide enough information (unless registration update processing is some screen I don't have) to know if it might be custom code or some other issue.

If you are sure that this isn't a bug in your code, you can make sure you are on the latest build of 2021 R2 (at least in a test instance where you can reproduce the problem) and then reach out to Acumatica support if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Brian. I ended up finding the solution, I had created userfields with datamember=Document, and not datamember=CurrentDocument. It was working randomly.